# If we are given that $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,6)$, find $B-A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we are given that $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,6)$, find $B-A$ where $B-A$ represents the difference of $B$ and $A$

Since $A$ contains numbers $0,1,2$ and $B$ contains numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ but not including $6$ wouldn't $B-A$ be the interval of $3-5$ or $B-A=[3,6)$ but the answer is $(2,6)$, why is that?

Comment: Assuming that the notations for the intervals refer to the standard usage, there are more than just $0$, $1$, and $2$ in the set $A$, for example.

Comment: The interval notation implies that we are talking about intervals *of real numbers*, not intervals of *integers*.  Note that $2.1\in B$ but $2.1\not\in A$.  Also $2.1\not\in [3,6)$.  You are correct that $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus\{0,1,2\}=\{3,4,5\}$, but that is the correct answer to the incorrect problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah yes, I forgot to mention it was real numbers, my bad. Thank you for the explanation! <3

Comment: Recall that $B-A= B \cap A^c$, if that helps

Comment: @leibnewtz that is a useful thing to remember when there is a convenient universal set to talk about.  I prefer to avoid that notation when speaking generally however since $A^c$ is not defined without an explicit universal set.

Comment: @JMoravitz In this case wouldn't the universal set just be $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @leibnewtz That would be a common and convenient choice for a universal set, yes.  Alternatively another equally convenient universal set would be $[0,6)=A\cup B$, but these are by no means the *only* choices for universal sets in this situation.  We could have used the complex numbers, or the union of the set of real numbers and the set of top 100 most popular cat names of 2017, etc...  Depending on which you choose, it might be more trouble than it is worth to think of it that way.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your point is well taken, I just feel like that's the natural choice for problems like these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=[0,2]={x:0\le x\le2},B=[1,6)={x:1\le x<6}$
$$A^c={x:x<0 or  x>2}$$
$$B-A=B\cap A^c={x:1\le x<6 and{x:x<0 or  x>2}}$$
$$={x:2<x<6}=(2,6)$$